# What is the advantage of using a git tag over an empty commit in git?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-tag

This question arises more out of curiosity and not due to issues faced while using git.

`git` allows you to make empty commits with `git commit -m "message" --allow-empty`

You can also tag specific revisions using `git tag -a v1.4 -m 'my version 1.4'`.

For all practical purposes I can think of right now, like making a tag to signify an important commit, deploying a particular tag, creating tag to specify version bumps, we can create an empty commit with the same message and then use it instead of the tag.

So, what is the advantage of using tags over empty commits, and vice versa?

Comment: Cool, I didn't know it was possible to make empty commits. Now I'm wondering why anyone would like to create empty commits, aside from many using them instead of tags… I wonder what was the thought behind the `--allow-empty` option and its intended usage.

Comment: @Leif Same here, I learned today that we can create empty commits, and immediately started wondering why you would need tags if you can store the same information in empty commits.

Comment: With a tag you can write `git checkout v1.4`. Without a tag you have to find the commit you want and then do `git checkout a29bff3` or whatever—much less straightforward. Tools like GitHub also treat tags specially in a similar way.

Comment: @Leif Also found a couple of good uses for empty commits [here](https://coderwall.com/p/m_pgbg) and [here](https://coderwall.com/p/vkdekq)

Comment: @bdesham So other than convenience / intuitiveness / ease of usability, are there any other reasons to use a tag?

Comment: Well, apart from the sanitation, medicine, education, wine, public order, irrigation, roads, the fresh water system, and public health—no, there are no reasons to use tags ;-)

Comment: @mu無 Thanks for the links. I guess you could also use it for things like `git commit -m "Important message for future developers." --allow-empty` although I'm sure there's a better place to post messages than leaving "breadcrumbs" in the Git history :p

Comment: @bdesham haha. I had guessed that convenience / intuitiveness / ease of usability would definitely be one reason, but wasn't sure if that was the only reason here. FWIW, I came across questions asking for difference b/w tag and branches, and an extra angle there was that branches can easily be deleted, and hence are unreliable.

Comment: Empty commit messages can often be used to log changes to a system that is not code related. For example to mark that you upgraded the production server operating system to the latest. Though not a code change but still important. Perhaps this is part of a pull request. Alternatively you could have a change log text file that marks these events. Another use case is as reminders. In cases where I have one PR depend on another PR I'll add a _TODO: Rebase after parent branch is merged_ empty commit so I see it in the history and know to `git rebase --interactive master` and drop the TODO commit.

Comment: https://fallthrough.io/2016/11/git-empty-commit/

Comment: Empty commits have the advantage of being retained during rebasing. (Maybe there's some simple git magic for retaining tags during a rebase, but idk.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can immediately checkout a tag. E.g. after deploy to production you do something like

```
git tag -f production
```

and if you ever need to test something, as it is deployed, you can do

```
git checkout production
```

Also, extra advantage: no empty commits!